# How do space-time rifts keep their position constant on Earth?

Tags: doctor-who, physics

In Doctor Who, a so called "rift" in the fabric space-time is created every so often usually as a direct or indirect result of the Doctor's own adventures. My question is that, as a tear in the very fabric of the Universe, how these rifts have a constant position on Earth (to name a couple, the Cardiff Space-Time Rift and the Coal Hill Space-Time Rift). As the Earth is always moving (it goes around the Sun, the Sun goes around the galaxy, etc.) surely it should leave these rifts in their place in space-time as it continues its journey and leave them behind?

Comment: While we're of course dealing with some arbitrary sci-fi physics here, let's notice for the safe of fairness that there is no absolute frame of reference which these rifts could be fixed to. This question appears to imply the opposite.

Comment: @voidptr - Precisely. In fact, it rather makes sense (insofar as Doctor Who makes sense) for a spacetime anomaly to be fixed relative to some massive object.

Comment: @void_ptr I'm thinking about if you could assign a coordinate to every point in space along the x, y, and z axis with anywhere you like as (0,0,0), then I'm imagining these rifts would have their own coordinates that the Earth would pass through and then likely never encounter again.

Comment: @Lawrence If you are referring to how space-time works in our Universe, then the answer is it does not work like that. However, the discussion of real-world theory of relativity is better suited for physics StackExchange.

Comment: *Wibbly-wobbly... timey-wimey... stuff.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How does anything keep its position constant on Earth? Earth's gravity.

There is no universal frame of reference, only relative frames of reference. So "in place" must be relative to *something*, and just like everything else we observe on Earth's surface, "in place" means - and can only mean - relative to the Earth, whose gravity dominates.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the Cardiff rift got dragged along for the ride when the Daleks used the Earth to build their superweapon.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the rift is relative to Cardiff. Not the specific location but rather the idea of Cardiff.